# BibLaTeX Superfluous punctuation and spacing in gost-inline (and gost-footnote) style

Tags: biblatex, spacing, punctuation

Sometimes the output of biblatex in `gost-inline` style (the same is for `style=gost-footnote`) has unnecessary space after a title of a citation and double punctuation between the author's name and the title (see MWE).

Is it a bug? How can I fix it?

I use the following versions:
Package: `biblatex 2018/11/02 v3.12`
File: `gost-inline.dbx 2018/02/20 v1.17`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-inline]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{TEST-biblatex-gost.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{TEST-biblatex-gost.bib}
@Book{Millimetron,
  author     = {John Millimetron},
  title      = {A title of the first book},
}
@Book{Ilusive,
  author     = {Joe Elusive},
  location   = {Lipsiae},
  title      = {A title of the second book},
  year       = {1871},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Here \autocite{Millimetron} is some \autocite{Ilusive} text \autocite{Millimetron}.
    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: The Problem]

---

### Update. Related Problem

The answer by **moewe** solved the two aforecited problems. But in my document I have a last one, which is related to the first above-mentioned one. So, I have the following entry:

```
@Unpublished{Antonin,
  author    = {Antonin Kapustin},
  title     = {Katalog of manuscripts of the Sinai monastery},
  year      = {1870},
  location  = {Sinai},
}
```

and the citation of it (`Text \autocite[12]{Antonin}.` ) still (with the moewe's code applied) gives a result with the superfluous spacing between the year and the page number:

[image: The problem2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superfluous space comes from an uncommented line end in the bibmacro `maintitle+volumes+parts+`. The double punctuation comes from a bare `\bibsentence` in `cite:opcit`. The first is easily fixed by adding a `%` ([What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864)), for the second issue I'm not sure why the `\bibsentence` is there in the first place, so the output with my workaround probably needs some careful scrutiny.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-inline]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+volumes+parts+}[1]{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{#1}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {\usebibmacro{#1}%
        \setunit{\addcolondelim}%
        \usebibmacro{involumes+otherparts}{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{volume+parts}{\newunit}}
       {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{involumes+otherparts}{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{volume+parts}{\newunit}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{#1}}}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:opcit}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
  \setunit*{\labelnamepunct}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Millimetron,
  author     = {John Millimetron},
  title      = {A title of the first book},
}
@book{Ilusive,
  author     = {Joe Elusive},
  location   = {Lipsiae},
  title      = {A title of the second book},
  year       = {1871},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Here \autocite{Millimetron} is some \autocite{Ilusive} text \autocite{Millimetron}.
    
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Here (Millimetron J. A title of the first book) is some (Elusive J. A title of the second book. Lipsiae, 1871) text (Millimetron J. Op. cit.).]

I reported the issues at https://github.com/odomanov/biblatex-gost/issues/29 and https://github.com/odomanov/biblatex-gost/issues/30.

---

### Update

The `biblatex-gost` maintainer has quickly resolved the two issues above and released version 1.20 of the style bundle.

The problem with your new entry is another missing `%`, this time in the driver for `@unpublished`. It has already been added (https://github.com/odomanov/biblatex-gost/commit/8d829bfcb854655f4ee7a3eb622bd422d50083a8), but in the meantime you can add the following to your preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=gost-inline]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{maintitle+volumes+parts+}[1]{%
  \iffieldsequal{maintitle}{#1}
    {\clearfield{maintitle}%
     \clearfield{mainsubtitle}%
     \clearfield{maintitleaddon}}
    {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
       {\usebibmacro{#1}%
        \setunit{\addcolondelim}%
        \usebibmacro{involumes+otherparts}{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{volume+parts}{\newunit}}
       {\usebibmacro{maintitle}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{involumes+otherparts}{\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{volume+parts}{\newunit}%
        \newunit
        \usebibmacro{#1}}}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{cite:opcit}{%
  \ifnameundef{labelname}
    {\printfield{label}}
    {\printnames{labelname}}%
  \setunit*{\labelnamepunct}%
  \printtext[bibhyperlink]{%
    \bibstring[\mkibid]{opcit}}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{unpublished}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{heading}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \setunit*{\labelnamepunct}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \setunit*{\addcolondelim}%
  \usebibmacro{translation}%
  \def\bbx@gost@respdelim{\setunit{\respdelim}}% ----- Resp starts -----
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \setunit*{\resppunct}%
  \usebibmacro{credits}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist[semicolondelim]{specdata}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{isbn}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{url+urldate+note}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{howpublished}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{relatedblock}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Millimetron,
  author     = {John Millimetron},
  title      = {A title of the first book},
}
@book{Ilusive,
  author     = {Joe Elusive},
  location   = {Lipsiae},
  title      = {A title of the second book},
  year       = {1871},
}
@Unpublished{Antonin,
  author    = {Antonin Kapustin},
  title     = {Katalog of manuscripts of the Sinai monastery},
  year      = {1870},
  location  = {Sinai},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Here \autocite{Millimetron} is some \autocite{Antonin} text \autocite{Millimetron}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: moewe, thanks a lot for the solution! It resolves these two problems. But in my document I have an another one, which is related to the first one. Please, see the addition info in my initial question.

Comment: Sorry, this is another missing %. Line 1305 of gost-standard.bbx. The change is on GitHub.

Comment: million thanks, guys, my problem is totally solved!